# Rails 3.2 and handling foreign keys in order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a table (let's call it `A` for simplicity's sake) with 4 integer columns in it (`slot1`, `slot2`, `slot3`, `slot4`). These 4 correspond to an ID in a different table (`B` to keep with the example).

I need to pull the data from the corresponding row in `B`, but here I've run into an issue. I'm trying to fetch the 4 slots with a `where()` method like so:

```
@a_item = A.where("publish_at <= ?", DateTime.now).last
@slots = B.where(:id => [@a_item.slot1, @a_item.slot2, @a_item.slot3, @a_item.slot4]) if @a_item != nil
```

But, of course, the order of the slots does not maintain in what I have returning, it is sorted by the ID of the `B` object.

So one dirty way of doing this is to fetch all 4 items individually, but before doing this, is there a better way to do this or potentially structure the relationships?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to return.  You want an order listed of B objects where the id is in that array of @a_item slots?  Can you clarify order do you want the responses to be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@a_item = A.order(:published_at).last
ids = [@a_item.slot1, @a_item.slot2, @a_item.slot3, @a_item.slot4] unless @a_item.nil?
@slots = B.find(ids) unless ids.nil?
results = ids.map { |id| @slots.detect { |slot| slot.id == id } }
```

I'll let you add in the rest of the resilience checks and failsafes incase nothing is returned where you expect something.